# Foreach and If linked issue

Tags: powershell

Here after my code for which I have an issue:

```
#Delivery Groups Information
$dgroup = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://${XMS}:4443/xenmobile/api/v1/deliverygroups/filter" -Body '{}' -Headers $headers -Method Post

$new = 0
$count = $dgroup.dglistdata.dglist.length
for ($v=0; $v -lt $count; $v++) {
    foreach ($dglistdata in $dgroup) {
        Write-Host $dglistdata.dglistdata.dglist[$new].name
        $new++
    }
}

$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "white"
$dgroup = Read-Host -Prompt "Please provide Delivery Group Name for which notification will be sent"
$message = Read-Host -Prompt "Please provide the message to be sent"

#Devices
$devices = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://${XMS}:4443/xenmobile/api/v1/device/filter" -Body '{}' -Headers $headers -Method Post

foreach ($device in $devices.filteredDevicesDataList) {
    Write-Output $device.id >$null
    Write-Output $device.platform >$null
}

foreach ($device in $devices.filteredDevicesDataList) {
    $url = "https://${XMS}:4443/xenmobile/api/v1/device/" + $device.id + "/deliverygroups"
    $global:dg = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get
    foreach($deliverygroups in $dg) {
        Write-Output $dg.deliveryGroups.name >$null
    }
}

foreach ($device in $devices.filteredDevicesDataList) {
    if ($dg.deliveryGroups.name -match $dgroup) {
        Write-Host $device.devicemodel
        Send-Notification
    } else {
        $dgroup = 0
    }
}
```

Info:

The main object of the code is to send notification to devices based on which group devices are member of.

Example:

iPad member of "DG 2"
iPhone member of "DG 1"

Result:

[image: Result]

Do I miss something there?

Comment: Please post the code as... code, not cropped screenshots. Also, the sample in the current screenshot is unlikely to be enough information to help you. What is `$dgroup`? What is `$dg`? How was `$devices` defined.

Comment: Here after the code:

Comment: Once again, please paste your _code_ - not screenshots. We can help you with the formatting if needed

Comment: What isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: Ansgar, iPad is member of DG 2 and iPhone is member of DG 1. When I provide DG 1 I should only see iPhone and not both, if I provide DG 2 I should see iPad and not no device

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think I found the solution, I need to include my loop for notification in the other loop as:

```
foreach($device in $devices.filteredDevicesDataList)
{
$url = "https://${XMS}:4443/xenmobile/api/v1/device/" + $device.id + "/deliverygroups"
$Global:dg=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get
foreach($deliverygroups in $dg)
{
write-output $dg.deliveryGroups.name >$Null
If($dg.deliveryGroups.name -match $dgroup)
{
write-host $device.devicemodel
Send-notification
}
}
}
```